# Libgdx display text/score as actor on stage

Tags: java, android, libgdx, stage

I would like to display multiple texts/scores on my stage. This [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19450627/libgdx-android-game-displaying-fixed-text-ie-score-over-a-scrolling-screen) suggested SpriteBatch, however, the issue is that these texts won’t fade out (not actor). Certain posts suggested use table, but the issue is that I can’t set texts' position on stage. Is there any other way to display texts as an actor on stage without using table?

Thanks in advance.
Zi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a subclass of actor and draw text as you like in it's overridden draw method.
Just don't forget to set alpha before drawing using setColor method. The value of alpha will be available as a parameter for draw.
You then can fade it the way you want.
Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @tanmay-patil. Can you please explain a little bit more in detail?

Comment: Well I forgot to ask. Have you given a try to the Label class? Now I feel like it can serve your purpose. If it does not have what you want, then you should try extending actor.

Comment: Thanks @tanmay-patil. do i have to use skin (as mentioned lots on other tutorial) in order to use Label class? i am still quite new to libgdx.

Comment: Yes. But you can get a default skin in libgdx tests to start with. No need to create your own right now.

Comment: It seems you forgot to add the atlas file. :) A skin comprises of 5 files. 1) your-skin-name.json file (containing description of skin), 2) font-name.fnt file (description of font), 3) font-name.png (actual font bitmap), 3) your-skin-name.png (containing all textures required by skin), 5) your-skin-name.atlas (description of textures in the atlas's png). If you are having a difficulty, I'll suggest to take a look at test skin, try using it and then making your own by looking at it's structure. Good luck.

Comment: He didnt forget anything of the kind. There is no atlas required for drawing text - he has to load a BitmapFont which he does.